# Invalid file format error when uploading MTL.txt file into QGIS

Tags: qgis, error, import, text

I am trying to upload a number of *MTL.txt* files into QGIS downloaded from USGS Earth Explorer. Although download is successful and I am able to import the other individual downloaded band data I am unable to do the same with the *MTL.txt* file. I receive the error:

> MTL.txt is not a valid or recognised data source.

I have tried using different Landsat data and download variations but with no avail. The data is downloaded onto my computer directly instead of any cloud based system.

Why can't the file be imported?

Comment: How are you importing it?

Comment: Is it the Landsat 8 surface reflectance file ?

Comment: @BERA I have been importing data using the drag and drop method into the layers panel. Would you recommend using an alternative method? Not sure if/what certain settings should be used in this circumstance?

Comment: @Taras yes it is the Landsat 8 surface reflectance file

Comment: You cant just add any text file to QGIS. What is the file structure, a comma delimited table? Then try Ctrl+Alt+T. What are you going to use it for?